# What is the difference between the results of array.split() and array.map(Number)?

Tags: javascript

```
a = '1 3 2 6 1 2'.split(' ');
a = a.map(Number);

console.log(a);
```

The output shown for `a.map(Number)` is :

```
Array(6)
0: 1
1: 3
2: 2
3: 6
4: 1
5: 2
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

and `a = '1 3 2 6 1 2'.split(' ')` is :

```
(6) ["1", "3", "2", "6", "1", "2"]
0:"1"
1:"3"
2:"2"
3:"6"
4:"1"
5:"2"
length:6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

What is the difference between this two array result?

Comment: After splitting, each item in the array is of type string...after map they are of type Number

Comment: `a.map(Number)` calls `Number()` on each element passing the value as parameter. i.e: `Number("1");` etc.. - The results are returned as new array - `a.split()` simply splits the string by the specified character returning an array - See docs on [**array map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - [**Number**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Examples) - [**string split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split returns strings whereas map returns integers.below is the snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or similar as they are not only not visible by everyone on all devices but also can not be interacted with as needed. It also depends on a third party site which may or may not be offline at times. See [**Why not to upload Images of Code when asking a Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) which also applies to answers. Stackoverflow has build-in code snippets you can use to demonstrate the result.

Answer (score 2):

After the `split`, you have an array of strings: `["1", "2", ...]`

After the `map`, you've converted each string to the equivalent number: `[1, 2, ...]`

You can see the difference here:

```js
var a = '1 3 2 6 1 2'.split(' ');
console.log("after split:", a);
a = a.map(Number);
console.log("after map:", a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That happened because `map`'s job is to call the callback you provide with each entry and build a new array from what it returns. If you call `Number` with a string, it converts it to a number (either a meaningful one, or `NaN` if the whole string can't be converted to a meaningful number).

Answer (score 1):

The call to `.split()` returns an array of strings from the original string. The subsequent call to `.map()` returns an array of *numbers* converted from the array of strings.

The `Number()` constructor, when called without `new`, converts the argument to a number and returns it. By passing `Number` to `.map()`, the strings from the first array are each converted to a number and collected in the second array.